# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, autoencoder

I want to write a denoising autoencoder and for the sake visualization purposes I would like to print out the corrupted images as well.

This is the testing part where I want to show the corrupted image:

```
def corrupt(x):
    noise = tf.random_normal(shape=tf.shape(x), mean=0.0, stddev=0.2, dtype=tf.float32) 
    return x + noise

# Testing
# Encode and decode images from test set and visualize their reconstruction
n = 10
canvas_orig = np.empty((28, 28 * n))
canvas_corrupt = np.empty((28, 28 * n))
canvas_recon = np.empty((28, 28 * n))

# MNIST test set
batch_x, _ = mnist.test.next_batch(n)

# Encode and decode the digit image and determine the test loss
g, l = sess.run([Y, loss], feed_dict={X: batch_x})

# Draw the generated digits
for i in range(n):
    # Original images
    canvas_orig[0: 28, i * 28: (i + 1) * 28] = batch_x[i].reshape([28, 28])

    # Corrupted images
    canvas_corrupt[0: 28, i * 28: (i + 1) * 28] = corrupt(batch_x[i]).reshape([28, 28]) 

    # Reconstructed images
    canvas_recon[0: 28, i * 28: (i + 1) * 28] = g[i].reshape([28, 28])    

print("Original Images")     
plt.figure(figsize=(n, 1))
plt.imshow(canvas_orig, origin="upper", cmap="gray")
plt.show()

print("Corrupted Images")     
plt.figure(figsize=(n, 1))
plt.imshow(canvas_corrupt, origin="upper", cmap="gray")
plt.show()

print("Reconstructed Images")
plt.figure(figsize=(n, 1))
plt.imshow(canvas_recon, origin="upper", cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

The error occurs on the following line:

```
canvas_corrupt[0: 28, i * 28: (i + 1) * 28] = corrupt(batch_x[i]).reshape([28, 28])
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work because the statements above and beneath it look very similar and work perfectly.
And the fact, that "reshape" is a function and not an attribute, confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `batch_x[i]` is a numpy array (which has a `reshape` method), while the result of `corrupt(...)` is a `Tensor` object. As of tf 1.5, it doesn't have a `reshape` method. This won't throw an error: `tf.reshape(corrupt(batch_x[i]), [28, 28]))`

But since your goal is to *visualize* the value, you should better avoid mixing up tensorflow and numpy operations and rewrite `corrupt` in terms of `numpy` only:

```
def corrupt(x):
    noise = np.random.normal(size=x.shape, loc=0.0, scale=0.2)
    return x + noise
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. As you said, now I just use `numpy` to generate the noise with `np.random.normal(0, 0.2, 784)`, so there is no problem any more with the `reshape()` function.