# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow for a long time, and when I try to run my code on jupyter notebook (having latest version of keras and tensorflow installed with pip), I get the following error when I try to reshape a tensor:

```
def loss_nrmse():
    def nrmse(y_true, y_pred):
        """
        Normalized Root Mean Squared Error (NRMSE)

        Parameters
        ----------
        y_true: np.array
            Ground truth samples
        y_pred: np.array
            predicted samples

        Returns
        -------
        nrmse: float
            Normalized root mean squared error
        """
        y_true = tf.reshape(y_true[:,:,:,0], y_pred.shape) # PROBLEM IS HERE

        one_data_shape = (1, y_pred.shape[1], y_pred.shape[2] , y_pred.shape[3])
        values = []
        for i in range(len(y_true)):
            y_t = tf.reshape(y_true[i], one_data_shape)
            y_p = tf.reshape(y_pred[i], one_data_shape)
            diff = tf.keras.backend.max(y_t) - tf.keras.backend.min(y_t)
            val = RootMeanSquaredError()(y_t, y_p) / diff
            values.append(val)
        return np.mean(values)
    return nrmse
```

and I get the only error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'reshape'

Could you help me please ?

Comment: You are mixing up tensors and numpy arrays, take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209045/15923186

Comment: Please help us to know the installed `TensorFlow` and `Python` version to understand the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Withe error pointing to this line in your code as you have correctly mentioned ,

> ```
>  y_true = tf.reshape(y_true[:,:,:,0], y_pred.shape) # PROBLEM IS HERE
> ```

As i dont have the shape of your data, I can only tell you that the number of elements in `y_true[:,:,:,0]` and `y_pred` should be the same .

You can as well convert your tensors to numpy arrays .

Use the following code :

```
def loss_nrmse():
    def nrmse(y_true, y_pred):
        
      y_true = np.array(y_true)
      y_pred = np.array(y_pred)           



     y_true = np.reshape(y_true[:,:,:,0], y_pred.shape)

        one_data_shape = (1, y_pred.shape[1], y_pred.shape[2] , y_pred.shape[3])
        values = []
        for i in range(len(y_true)):
            y_t = tf.reshape(y_true[i], one_data_shape)
            y_p = tf.reshape(y_pred[i], one_data_shape)
            diff = tf.keras.backend.max(y_t) - tf.keras.backend.min(y_t)
            val = RootMeanSquaredError()(y_t, y_p) / diff
            values.append(val)
        return np.mean(values)
    return nrmse
```